# Not able to Run Jar file on AWS EC2 - Could not create the directory where the uploaded files will be stored

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, amazon-ec2, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I can able to run the JAR file from local. But When I did uploaded the code to the Ubuntu 18.4 server AWS EC2, I am not able to run the JAR file.

By saying java -jar MyjarfileName.jar

**Getting Error -**

**Could not create the directory where the uploaded files will be stored.**

**Details Error -**

SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/echeckinfo-backend/target/seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT)

2022-06-20 16:44:41.543  INFO 21492 --- [           main] c.s.app.SeamlesschequeApiApplication     : Starting SeamlesschequeApiApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on ip-172-26-5-71 with PID 21492 (/home/ubuntu/echeckinfo-backend/target/seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by ubuntu in /home/ubuntu/echeckinfo-backend/target)
2022-06-20 16:44:41.566  INFO 21492 --- [           main] c.s.app.SeamlesschequeApiApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-06-20 16:44:41.717  INFO 21492 --- [           main] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-06-20 16:44:41.718  INFO 21492 --- [           main] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2022-06-20 16:44:45.398  INFO 21492 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode!
2022-06-20 16:44:45.402  INFO 21492 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-06-20 16:44:45.817  INFO 21492 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 407ms. Found 25 repository interfaces.
2022-06-20 16:44:46.706  INFO 21492 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'seamlesschequeApiApplication' of type [com.seamlesscheque.app.SeamlesschequeApiApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$be13dd17] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2022-06-20 16:44:47.528  INFO 21492 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 5000 (http)
2022-06-20 16:44:47.602  INFO 21492 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-06-20 16:44:47.603  INFO 21492 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.13
2022-06-20 16:44:47.621  INFO 21492 --- [           main] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib]
2022-06-20 16:44:47.792  INFO 21492 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-06-20 16:44:47.793  INFO 21492 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6075 ms
2022-06-20 16:44:48.534  INFO 21492 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[139.59.18.83:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
2022-06-20 16:44:48.799  INFO 21492 --- [.59.18.83:27017] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:6108}] to 139.59.18.83:27017
2022-06-20 16:44:48.833  INFO 21492 --- [.59.18.83:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=139.59.18.83:27017, type=STANDALONE, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[5, 0, 0]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=13, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=29872868}
2022-06-20 16:44:50.226  INFO 21492 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:6109}] to 139.59.18.83:27017
2022-06-20 16:44:51.877  WARN 21492 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fileController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'fileService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/echeckinfo-backend/target/seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/seamlesscheque/app/service/FileServiceImpl.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.seamlesscheque.app.service.FileServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.seamlesscheque.app.exception.FileStorageException: Could not create the directory where the uploaded files will be stored.
2022-06-20 16:44:51.890  INFO 21492 --- [           main] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:6109}] to 139.59.18.83:27017 because the pool has been closed.
2022-06-20 16:44:51.895  INFO 21492 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2022-06-20 16:44:51.943  INFO 21492 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-06-20 16:44:51.955 ERROR 21492 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'fileController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'fileService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/echeckinfo-backend/target/seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/seamlesscheque/app/service/FileServiceImpl.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.seamlesscheque.app.service.FileServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.seamlesscheque.app.exception.FileStorageException: Could not create the directory where the uploaded files will be stored.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.seamlesscheque.app.SeamlesschequeApiApplication.main(SeamlesschequeApiApplication.java:37) [seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.23.RELEASE-exec.jar:1.0.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.23.RELEASE-exec.jar:1.0.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.23.RELEASE-exec.jar:1.0.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.launch(ThinJarLauncher.java:193) [spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.23.RELEASE-exec.jar:1.0.23.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.thin.ThinJarLauncher.main(ThinJarLauncher.java:140) [spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.23.RELEASE-exec.jar:1.0.23.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.launch(ThinJarWrapper.java:140) [seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.main(ThinJarWrapper.java:107) [seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileServiceImpl' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/echeckinfo-backend/target/seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/seamlesscheque/app/service/FileServiceImpl.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.seamlesscheque.app.service.FileServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.seamlesscheque.app.exception.FileStorageException: Could not create the directory where the uploaded files will be stored.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:304) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:285) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1154) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1237) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.seamlesscheque.app.service.FileServiceImpl]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is com.seamlesscheque.app.exception.FileStorageException: Could not create the directory where the uploaded files will be stored.
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:300) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.seamlesscheque.app.exception.FileStorageException: Could not create the directory where the uploaded files will be stored.
    at com.seamlesscheque.app.service.FileServiceImpl.<init>(FileServiceImpl.java:46) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 49 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/echeckpiiweb
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767) ~[na:1.8.0_312]
    at com.seamlesscheque.app.service.FileServiceImpl.<init>(FileServiceImpl.java:44) ~[seamlesscheque-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem. In order to run this -

First we have to run our project in sudo mode.

sudo java -jar myjarfileName.jar

**Note -**

1. Make sure you have java installed

   - sudo apt-update
   - sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jdk)
   - export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
   - java -version
2. Make sure you have maven installed

   - sudo apt-get install maven
   - mvn -version
3. Make sure you can able to build your application

**Note -** It will take some of the time to start. Once its start, you can ran your application, it will create all the directory, you can remove sudo, and ran it again. by saying -

```
java -jar myjarfileName.jar
```